# Images are not floating up

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to float a row of 4 images. However, they are not floating. I will attach my code and a screenshot of the website as it is locally hosted. I have tried putting the float in other parts of the CSS such as in the `#sidebar{float:left;}`. I am not sure why it will not float. I have also tried `.left{float:left}` but that just makes the sidebar smaller. I am very confused about this.

```css
/* ----- Fonts CSS ----- */

body {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ----- End Fonts CSS ----- */

.indexBody {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("city.jpg");
  color: #fff;
}

#textLogo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
}


/*---- Index Page ----*/

.serviceTitle {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.serviceImage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.5%;
  margin-bottom: 9%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 600px;
}

a .serviceImage:hover {
  background-image: url("IMG_3134.jpg");
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*---- Photograohy Portfolio Index Page ----*/

nav ul {
  width: 75%;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

.photoBody {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#photogLogo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.main1 {
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}

.row1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/*Test*/

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body class="photoBody">
  <div class="left">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div class="navigation">
        <h1 id="photogLogo">Text Logo</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="main1">
      <img class="row1" src="IMG_4085.jpg" alt="Coastline" />
      <img class="row1" src="IMG_4085.jpg" alt="Coastline" />
      <img class="row1" src="IMG_4085.jpg" alt="Coastline" />
      <img class="row1" src="IMG_4085.jpg" alt="Coastline" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: This image is a screenshot of the website]

Comment: Your are using `clear:both` remove it and `float:left` to sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want, this a way to do it :

```
 .main1{
    width: 35%;
    clear: both;
}

.row1{
    display:block;
    left:0;
    float:left;
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gsxeoozo/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
/* ----- Fonts CSS ----- */

body {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ----- End Fonts CSS ----- */

.indexBody {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("city.jpg");
  color: #fff;
}

#textLogo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
}


/*---- Index Page ----*/

.serviceTitle {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.serviceImage {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.5%;
  margin-bottom: 9%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  width: 600px;
}

a .serviceImage:hover {
  background-image: url("IMG_3134.jpg");
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}


/*---- Photograohy Portfolio Index Page ----*/

nav ul {
  width: 75%;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

.photoBody {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#photogLogo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.main1 {
  width: 70%;
  text-align: left;
}

.row1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}


/*Test*/

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Sample Project</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class="photoBody">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="navigation">
      <h1 id="photogLogo">Text Logo</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main1">
    <img class="row1" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Coastline" />
    <img class="row1" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Coastline" />
    <img class="row1" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Coastline" />
    <img class="row1" src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="Coastline" />
  </div>

</div>
```